# $f$ is entire if $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous and defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$. I wish to show that $f$ is entire if $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$. Taking $z = x + iy$ and $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ leads to $$u(x,y) = u(x,-y)\\
-v(x,y) = v(x,-y)$$
though I do not know how to proceed from here, or if this is even the correct approach. It seems $u$ must be an even function and $v$ an odd one, at least with respect to $y$.

Comment: where if $f$ defined? is it continuous? smooth? pleazse give more details

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez Sorry I must have forgotten to include that, I have edited my question.

Comment: Consider the function which just takes the real part of $z$.

Comment: Given real $\,a,b\,$ and $\,f(x+iy):=ax+iby.\,$ It satisfies $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written now, this is not true. Take for example the function $f(z) = \bar{z}$. It is not holomorphic but satisfies your identity

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting and perhaps explains some of my confusion with this question.